# Как при наведении на элемент заменить курсор картинкой?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как можно при наведении на элемент заменить стандартный вид курсора картинкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `cursor: url`. Описание можно посмотреть например [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/cursor).

```
div:hover {
    cursor: url('путь к вашему курсору') auto !important;
}
```